How to filter elements in a document using another results of another filter?
This may be simpler to explain with an example. Consider the following simple json:
[
  {"id": 1, "ref":32, "key":10},
  {"id": 2, "ref":32, "key":75},
  {"id": 3, "ref":27, "key":13},
  {"id": 4, "ref":27, "key":42},
  {"id": 5, "ref":438, "key":42}
]

I want to select using jq all elements that have a ref such that there is an element with that ref and key equal to 42.
select * from table where ref in (select ref from table where key = 42)

I am totally stumped. I have managed to get the array of such ref '[.[]|select(.key==42).ref]'
I am even unclear how to select elements with .ref in a hard-coded  list, e.g.
this returns elements that have ref == 32: .[] | select(.ref == 32)
But I do not know how to select records that have ref in the list [32,45].


I am even unclear how to select elements with .ref in a hard-coded list, e.g. this returns elements that have ref == 32: .[] | select(.ref == 32)
But I do not know how to select records that have ref in the list [32,45].

In this case, just compare the .ref value to a stream of static values: .[] | select(.ref == (32,45)).
With longer lists, you could improve on its efficiency by having any control the comparisons, so that on the first match it could break out and immediately continue with the next item: .[] | select(any(.ref; . == (32,438))). Since jq 1.6, this pattern is implemented by the IN shortcut: .[] | select(IN(.ref; 32,438)).

select ref from table where key = 42

map(select(.key == 42).ref) will give you the array [27,438].

select * from table where ref in (…)

Save the previous result array into a variable using as, then iterate over this reference to get its items as a stream:
map(select(.key == 42).ref) as $refs | .[] | select(.ref == $refs[])
# or
map(select(.key == 42).ref) as $refs | .[] | select(IN(.ref; $refs[]))

{
  "id": 3,
  "ref": 27,
  "key": 13
}
{
  "id": 4,
  "ref": 27,
  "key": 42
}
{
  "id": 5,
  "ref": 438,
  "key": 42
}

Demo or Demo
To instead receive an array of items, just replace .[] | … with map(…).

Another approach could be to group the input array's items by their .ref value, then unpack each group if there's at least one item having .key == 42. Note that due to the initial grouping, the order of the output items might be different.
group_by(.ref)[] | select(any(.key == 42))[]

Demo
To instead receive an array of items, wrap the whole filter into brackets: […].
